# The Uniqueness of IOCTL_MOUNTDEV_QUERY_UNIQUE_ID

Tags: winapi, ioctl, mount-point

The documentation on [`IOCTL_MOUNTDEV_QUERY_UNIQUE_ID`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff560441.aspx) is a bit confusing... exactly *what* kind of ID should be returned in the `MOUNTDEV_UNIQUE_ID` structure?

The documentation for

```
typedef struct _MOUNTDEV_UNIQUE_ID {
  USHORT  UniqueIdLength;
  UCHAR  UniqueId[1];
} MOUNTDEV_UNIQUE_ID, *PMOUNTDEV_UNIQUE_ID;
```

says:

> `UniqueIdLength`
>
> - Contains the length of unique volume ID.
>
> `UniqueId`
>
> - Contains the unique volume ID. The format for unique volume names is `"\??\Volume{GUID}\"`, where GUID is a globally unique identifier that identifies the volume.

However, there's something weird here: What should be the exact format of `UniqueId`? If it's meant to be in the `\??\Volume{GUID}\` format, then what's the point of the `UniqueIdLength` field -- aren't they all the same size? Otherwise, what format does the device ID need to be in?

Furthermore, is this a *device* ID or a *volume* ID? In other words, is this supposed to be unique per *medium* (e.g. CD) or per *device* (CD drive)?

Comment: The definition given here for `UniqueId` is mistaken. The current docs have the right definition: "Contains the unique volume ID as an array of bytes". Volume GUID names in some cases are based directly on the unique volume ID, but in other cases the unique ID has to be mapped to a volume GUID name in the "MountedDevices" key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This kind of struct is pretty common in MS APIs - the `UniqueID[1]` variable is just a placeholder, in reality it's used as a `UniqueId[UniqueIdLength]` variable.

The ID is unique both per medium and per device - it depends on whether you're talking to a volume driver or a device class driver. The ID is intended to identify "something that can be mounted" - so e.g. a CD-ROM device, a fixed disk partition or an unpartitioned removable disk. The mount manager uses the ID a.o. to lookup where this particular volume was mounted before, and remount it at the same point.

Comment: @Eric: Sorry, I think my question was misleading. By *fixed-size* I wasn't referring to the `[1]` (I know how C works!), but the fact that the \??\Volume{GUID}\ string would always have the same length (about 35 characters I think?)... so why do you need another length field? Also, about the uniqueness: For a program like ImDisk, would it be per virtual disk?

Comment: @Mehrdad: Currently the name's 35 or so chars - but fixing that would break any possibility of extending the mount manager, so IMO it makes perfect sense to use a counted string. As far as I'm aware, the ID is persistent and unique for anything that can be mounted as a drive letter - whether that is a partition on a fixed disk, a CD-ROM drive or an unpartitioned but formatted USB stick. I don't know ImDisk - but the same rule should hold, the unique ID identifies that which can be mounted as a drive.

Comment: Ah okay, thanks for the info. :) (Btw, just noticed I misspelled your name last time.. :[ )

Answer (score 0):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff562264%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Maybe there is misunderstanding about this structure.

I called `DeviceIoControl(IOCTL_MOUNTDEV_QUERY_UNIQUE_ID)` and got a string as the similar format to Device Interface Path, but it is just different of the prefix 4 characters, and then it saved in registry `\HKLM\SYSTEM\MountedDevices`.

Answer (score 0):

`MOUNTDEV_UNIQUE_ID` is acquired upon a volume arrival notification where `mountmgr!MountMgrMountedDeviceArrival` invokes `mountmgr!QueryDeviceInformation`, which sends a `IOCTL_MOUNTDEV_QUERY_UNIQUE_ID` IRP to the volume PDO stack, which volmgr picks up, and I'm not sure what routine it is but in XP's ftdisk it was `ftdisk!FtpQueryUniqueIdBuffer` that determined whether to set the UniqueID member to a GPT partition GUID, a MBR signature + offset, or the symbolic link like `STORAGE#RemovableMedia...`. The symbolic link is based on the name of devnode that the volume PDO is part of, and the symbolic link was generated by `IoRegisterDeviceInterface`, which was then stored in the volume extension before alerting mountmgr of the volume arrival in the first place (alerting is done by `IoSetDeviceInterfaceState Enable`). On Windows 7 the volume PDO devnode name is `STORAGE\Volume\_??_USBSTOR#Disk&Ven_SanDisk&Prod_Cruzer_B lade&Rev_1.27#4C530399920812105355&0#{53f5630d-b6bf-11d0-94f2-00a0c91efb8b}`, the symbolic link is `STORAGE#Volume#_??_USBSTOR#Disk&Ven_SanDisk&Prod_Cruzer_Blade&Rev_1.27#4C530399920812105355&0#{53f56307-b6bf-11d0-94f2-00a0c91efb8b}#{53f5630d-b6bf-11d0-94f2-00a0c91efb8b}` but the MountedDevices data is `_??_USBSTOR#Disk&Ven_SanDisk&Prod_Cruzer_Blade&Rev_1.27#4C530399920812105355&0#{53f56307-b6bf-11d0-94f2-00a0c91efb8b}#{53f5630d-b6bf-11d0-94f2-00a0c91efb8b}`. The symbolic link that is created is always to the volume PDO name, because the volume PDO is supplied to the call, which is `\Device\HarddiskVolumeX`.

`FtpQueryUniqueIdBuffer` uses the MBR signature and partition offset if it's an MBR disk, and uses the GPT partition GUID if it's a GPT disk, and uses the symbolic link if it's neither, which tends to be a regular USB drive mass storage volume that doesn't have a boot sector, and ftdisk considers a disk without a boot sector to be a 'superfloppy', so it looks for that flag on the volume extension. So that's how unique it is, MBR signature  and GPT GUID uniqueness speak for themselves, but the symlink doesn't so I'll elaborate: it contains the DIID of the USBSTOR device, which includes the USB serial number, or if it doesn't have one, a system wide unique number determine according to the following [scheme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21374134/how-to-parse-usb-device-instance-id-diid/72512840#72512840).

Mountmgr creates further symbolic links between the drive letter and volume device name, and the volume GUID and the volume device name, and then puts them in the MountedDevices database but uses the unique ID instead of the volume device name. The volume GUID `\??\Volume{GUID}\` it generates using `ExUuidCreate`. `IOCTL_MOUNTMGR_QUERY_POINTS` shows each symbolic link for a mounted device, so it will show `\DosDevices\C: -> \Device\HarddiskVolumeX` and `\??\Volume{GUID}\ -> \Device\HarddiskVolumeX` and the unique ID of the mounted device and the name of the mounted device. It does not however show the symbolic link to `\Device\HarddiskVolumeX` created by `IoRegisterDeviceInterface` because the symbolic link wasn't created by mount manager, so it doesn't know about it.