# How are software interrupts triggered in windows when the IRQL drops?

Tags: windows, kernel, interrupt

I know that for hardware interrupts, when KeLowerIrql is called by KeAcquireInterruptSpinLock, the HAL adjusts the interrupt mask in the LAPIC, which will allow queued interrupts (in the IRR probably) to be serviced automatically. But with software interrupts, for instance, ntdll.dll sysenter calls to the SSDT NtXxx system services, how are they 'postponed' and triggered when the IRQL goes to passive level Same goes for the DPC dispatcher software interrupt (if the DPC is for the current CPU and of high priority), how is that triggered when IRQL < Dispatch IRQL? Do the software interrupt called functions (NtXxx) in the SSDT all loop on a condition i.e.

```
while (irql != passive)
```

Exactly the same question for lazy IRQL:

> Because accessing a PIC is a relatively slow operation, HALs that require accessing the I/O bus to change IRQLs, such as for PIC and 32-bit Advanced Configuration and Power Interface (ACPI) systems, implement a performance optimization, called lazy IRQL, that avoids PIC accesses. When the IRQL is raised, the HAL notes the new IRQL internally instead of changing the interrupt mask. If a lower-priority interrupt subsequently occurs, the HAL sets the interrupt mask to the settings appropriate for the first interrupt and does not quiesce the lower-priority interrupt until the IRQL is lowered (thus keeping the interrupt pending). Thus, if no lower-priority interrupts occur while the IRQL is raised, the HAL doesn’t need to modify the PIC.

How does it keep this interrupt pending? Does it just loop on a condition until the higher priority ISR lowers the IRQL and when the thread is scheduled in, the condition will eventually be met? Is it just that simple?

Edit: I must be missing out on something here because let's say an ISR at Device IRQL requests a DPC using IoRequestDpc, if it is a high priority DPC and the target is the current processor then it schedules an interrupt of DPC/Dispatch level to drain the processor's DPC queue. This is all happening in the ISR which is at Device IRQL (DIRQL) which means that the software interrupt with Dispatch/DPC IRQL level will spin at KeAcquireInterruptSpinLock I *think* because the current IRQL is too high, but wouldn't it be spinning there forever because the actual routine to lower the IRQL is called after the ISR returns meaning that it's going to stay stuck in the ISR at Device IRQL waiting on that software interrupt which requires IRQL < Dispatch/DPC IRQL (2), not only that, the dispatcher will not be able to dispatch the next thread because the dispatch DPC runs at Dispatch/DPC IRQL level which is far lower. There 1 solution I can think of.

1) The ISR returns the KDPC object to the KiInterruptDispatch so that it knows what priority the DPC is and then schedules it itself *after* it has lowered the IRQL using KeReleaseInterruptSpinLock but KSERVICE_ROUTINE only returns an unrelated boolean value so this is ruled out.

Does anyone know how this situation is avoided?

Edit 2: Perhaps it spawns a new thread that blocks waiting for IRQL < Dispatch IRQL and then returns from the ISR and drops the IRQL.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is something that isn't really explained explicitly on any source and interestingly enough the [second comment](http://www.osronline.com/article.cfm?article=529) also asks the same question.

Firstly, DPC software interrupts aren't like regular SSDT software interrupts, which are not postponed and run at passive IRQL and can be interrupted at any time. DPC software interrupts do not use `int` or `syscall` or anything like that, are postponed and run at dispatch level.

After studying the ReactOS kernel and WRK, I now know exactly what happens

A driver, when it receives `IRP_MN_START_DEVICE` from the PnP manager, initialises an interrupt object using [`IoConnectInterrupt`](https://github.com/Zer0Mem0ry/ntoskrnl/blob/master/Ke/amd64/intobj.c) using the data in the `CM_RESOURCE_LIST` it receives in the IRP. Of particular interest is the vector and affinity that was assigned by the PnP manager to the device (which is simple to do if the device exposes an MSI capability in its PCIe configuration space as it doesn't have to worry about underlying IRQ routing). It passes the vector, a pointer to an ISR, context for the ISR, IRQL to `IoConnectInterrupt` which calls `KeInitializeInterrupt` to initialise the interrupt object using the parameters and then it calls `KeConnectInterrupt` which switches the affinity of the current thread to the target processor, locks the dispatcher database and checks that that IDT entry points to a BugCheck wrapper `KxUnexpectedInterrupt0[IdtIndex]`. If it is then it raises IRQL to 31 so the following is an atomic operation and uses the HAL API to enable the vector that was mapped by the PnP manager on the LAPIC and assign it a TPR priority level corresponding to the IRQL. It then maps the vector to the handler address in the IDT entry for ther vector. To do this it passes the address `&Interrupt->DispatchCode[0]` into the IDT mapping routine `KeSetIdtHandlerAddress`. It appears this is a [template](https://reactos.org/archives/public/ros-diffs/2006-August/013809.html) which is the same for all interrupt objects which according to the WRK is `KiInterruptTemplate`. Sure enough, checking ReactOS kernel, we see in `KeInitializeInterrupt` -- which is called by `IoConnectInterrupt` -- the code:

```
 RtlCopyMemory(Interrupt->DispatchCode,
               KiInterruptDispatchTemplate,
               sizeof(Interrupt->DispatchCode));
```

`KiInterruptDispatchTemplate` appears to be blank for now, because ReactOS's amd64 port is in early development. On windows it will be implemented however and as the `KiInterruptTemplate`.

It then lowers the IRQL back to the old IRQL. If the IDT entry did not point to a BugCheck ISR then it initialises a chained interrupt -- because there was already an address at the IDT entry. It uses `CONTAINING_RECORD` to acquire the interrupt object by its member, the address of the handler (`DispatchCode[0]`) and connects the new interrupt object to the one already present, initialising the interrupt object already referenced's `LIST_ENTRY` as the head of the list and marking it as a chained interrupt by setting the `DispatchAddress` member to the address of `KiChainedDispatch`. It then drops the dispatcher database spinlock and switches the affinity back and returns the interrupt object.

The driver then sets up a DPC -- with the `DeferredRoutine` as a member -- for the Device Object using `IoInitializeDpcRequest`.

```
FORCEINLINE VOID IoInitializeDpcRequest ( _In_ PDEVICE_OBJECT DeviceObject, _In_ PIO_DPC_ROUTINE DpcRoutine )
    KeInitializeDpc(&DeviceObject->Dpc,
               (PKDEFERRED_ROUTINE) DpcRoutine,
               DeviceObject);
```

`KeInitializeDpc` calls `KiInitializeDpc` which is [hard-coded](https://doxygen.reactos.org/d1/d92/dpc_8c.html#ae288b59fa56efcc73de60cc1b6127923) to set the priority to medium which means that `KeInsertQueueDpc` will place it in the middle of the DPC queue. `KeSetImportanceDpc` and `KeSetTargetProcessorDpc` can be used after the call to set the returned DPC that was generated's priority and target processor respectively. It copies a DPC object to the member of the device object and if there is already a DPC object then it queues it to the DPC already present.

When the interrupt happens, the `KiInterruptTemplate` template of the interrupt object is the address in the IDT that gets called which will then [call the real interrupt dispatcher](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=WZdCAwAAQBAJ&pg=PT172&lpg=PT172&dq=KiChainedDispatch&source=bl&ots=njjLDmdbud&sig=ACfU3U1lW04ikH7vrT9N20Cyhp2cIhhldg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjB7633x__gAhVpRhUIHb9GC6sQ6AEwAXoECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=KiChainedDispatch&f=false) which is the `DispatchAddress` member which will be `KiInterruptDispatch` for a normal interrupt or `KiChainedDispatch` for a chained interrupt. It passes the interrupt object to `KiInterruptDispatch` (it can do this because, as we saw earlier, `RtlCopyMemory` copied `KiInterruptTemplate` into the interrupt object, this means that it can use an asm block with a relative RIP to acquire the address of the interrupt object it belongs to (it could also attempt to do something with the `CONTAINING_RECORD` function) but `intsup.asm` contains the following code to do it : `lea rbp, KiInterruptTemplate - InDispatchCode ; get interrupt object address  jmp qword ptr InDispatchAddress[rbp]; finish in common code`). `KiInterruptDispatch` will then acquire the interrupt's spinlock, probably using `KeAcquireInterruptSpinLock`. The ISR (`ServiceContext`) calls `IoRequestDpc` with the device object address that was created for the device and ISR, as a parameter, along with interrupt specific context and an optional IRP (which I'm guessing it gets from the head at `DeviceObject->Irp` if the routine is meant to handle an IRP). I expected it to be a single line wrapper of `KeInsertQueue` but passing the Dpc member of the device object instead and that's exactly what it is: `KeInsertQueueDpc(&DeviceObject->Dpc, Irp, Context);`. Firstly `KeInsertQueue` raises the IRQL from the device IRQL of the ISR to 31 which prevents all preemption. [WRK](https://github.com/markjandrews/wrk-v1.2/blob/master/base/ntos/ke/dpcobj.c) contains the following on line 263 of `dpcobj.c`:

```
#if !defined(NT_UP)

    if (Dpc->Number >= MAXIMUM_PROCESSORS) {
        Number = Dpc->Number - MAXIMUM_PROCESSORS;
        TargetPrcb = KiProcessorBlock[Number];

    } else {
        Number = CurrentPrcb->Number;
        TargetPrcb = CurrentPrcb;
    }
```

Which suggests that the `DPC->Number` member must be set by `KeSetTargetProcessorDpc` as target core number + maximum processors. This is bizarre and sure enough I went and looked at ReactOS's `KeSetTargetProcessorDpc` and it does! `KiProcessorBlock` appears to be a kernel structure for fast-accessing the KPRCB structures for each of the cores.

It then gets the core's normal DPC queue spinlock using `DpcData = KiSelectDpcData(TargetPrcb, Dpc)` which returns `&Prcb->DpcData[DPC_NORMAL]` as the type of the DPC it passed to it is normal, not threaded. It then acquires the spinlock for the queue and this appears to be an empty function body on ReactOS and I think it's because of this:

> /* On UP builds, spinlocks don't exist at IRQL >= DISPATCH */

And that makes sense because ReactOS only supports 1 core meaning there is no thread on another core that can access the DPC queue (a core might have a target DPC for this core's queue). There is only one DPC queue. If it were a multicore system it would have to acquire the spinlock so these look to be placeholders for when multicore functionality is implemented. If it failed to acquire the spinlock for the DPC queue then it would either spin-wait at IRQL 31 or drop to the IRQL of the interrupt itself and spinwait, allowing other interrupts to occur to the core but no other threads to run on the core.

Note that windows would use `KeAcquireSpinLockAtDpcLevel` to acquire this spinlock, ReactOS does not. `KeAcquireSpinLockAtDpcLevel` [does not touch the IRQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/wdm/nf-wdm-keacquirespinlockatdpclevel). Although, in the WRK it directly uses `KiAcquireSpinLock` which can be seen on line 275 of `dpcobj.c` which only acquires the spinlock and does nothing to the IRQL (`KiAcquireSpinLock(&DpcData->DpcLock);`).

After acquiring the spinlock it firstly ensures that the DPC object isn't already on a queue (`DpcData` member would be null when it does a `cmpxchg` to initialise it with the `DpcData` returned from `KiSelectDpcData(TargetPrcb, Dpc)`) and if it is it drops the spinlock and returns; otherwise, it then sets the DPC members to point to the interrupt specific context that was passed and then it inserts it into the queue either at the head (`InsertHeadList(&DpcData->DpcListHead, &Dpc->DpcListEntry);`) or the tail (`InsertTailList(&DpcData->DpcListHead, &Dpc->DpcListEntry);`)based on its priority (`if (Dpc->Importance == HighImportance)`). It then makes sure that a DPC isn't executing already `if (!(Prcb->DpcRoutineActive) && !(Prcb->DpcInterruptRequested))`. It then checks if `KiSelectDpcData` returned the second `KDPC_DATA` structure i.e. the DPC was of type threaded (`if (DpcData == &TargetPrcb->DpcData[DPC_THREADED])`) and if it is and `if ((TargetPrcb->DpcThreadActive == FALSE) && (TargetPrcb->DpcThreadRequested == FALSE))` then it does a locked `xchg` to set `TargetPrcb->DpcSetEventRequest` to true respectively and then it sets `TargetPrcb->DpcThreadRequested` and `TargetPrcb->QuantumEnd` to true and it sets `RequestInterrupt` to true if the target PRCB is the current PRCB otherwise it only sets it to true if the target core is not idle.

Now comes the crux of the original question. The WRK now contains the following code:

```
#if !defined(NT_UP)

            if (CurrentPrcb != TargetPrcb) {
                if (((Dpc->Importance == HighImportance) ||
                     (DpcData->DpcQueueDepth >= TargetPrcb->MaximumDpcQueueDepth))) {

                    if (((KiIdleSummary & AFFINITY_MASK(Number)) == 0) ||
                        (KeIsIdleHaltSet(TargetPrcb, Number) != FALSE)) {

                        TargetPrcb->DpcInterruptRequested = TRUE;
                        RequestInterrupt = TRUE;
                    }
                }

            } else {
                if ((Dpc->Importance != LowImportance) ||
                    (DpcData->DpcQueueDepth >= TargetPrcb->MaximumDpcQueueDepth) ||
                    (TargetPrcb->DpcRequestRate < TargetPrcb->MinimumDpcRate)) {

                    TargetPrcb->DpcInterruptRequested = TRUE;
                    RequestInterrupt = TRUE;
                }
            }

#endif
```

In essence, on a multiprocessor system, if the target core it acquired from the DPC object is not the current core of the thread then: If the DPC is of high importance or it exceeds the maximum queue depth and the logical `and` of the target affinity and the idle cores is 0 (i.e. the target core is not idle) and (well, `KeIsIdleHaltSet` appears to to be exactly the same thing (it checks the Sleeping flag in the target PRCB)) then **it sets a `DpcInterruptRequested` flag in the PRCB of the target core**. If the target of the DPC is the current core then if the DPC is not low importance (note: this would allow medium!) or if the DPC queue depth exceeds the maximum queue depth and if the request rate of DPCs on the core hasn't exceeded the minimum it **sets a flag in the PRCB of the current core** to indicate there is a DPC.

It now releases the DPC queue spinlock: `KiReleaseSpinLock(&DpcData->DpcLock);`(`#if !defined(NT_UP)` of course) (which doesn't alter the IRQL). It then checks to see if an interrupt was requested by the procedure (`if (RequestInterrupt == TRUE)`), then if it is a uniprocessor system (`#if defined(NT_UP)`) it simply calls `KiRequestSoftwareInterrupt(DISPATCH_LEVEL);` but if it is a multicore system it needs to check the target PRCB to see if it needs to send an IPI.

```
if (TargetPrcb != CurrentPrcb) {
    KiSendSoftwareInterrupt(AFFINITY_MASK(Number), DISPATCH_LEVEL);

    } else {
        KiRequestSoftwareInterrupt(DISPATCH_LEVEL);
    }
```

And it speaks for itself what that does; if the current PRCB is not the target PRCB of the DPC then it sends an IPI of `DISPATCH_LEVEL` priority to the processor number using `KiSendSoftwareInterrupt`; otherwise, it uses `KiRequestSoftwareInterrupt`. There is no documentation at all but my guess is this is a Self IPI, and it will wrap a HAL function that programs the ICR to send an IPI to itself at dispatch level priority (my reasoning being ReactOS at this stage calls [`HalRequestSoftwareInterrupt`](https://doxygen.reactos.org/d2/d8f/hal_2halarm_2generic_2pic_8c.html#ac06227bbf507880cbff06875d4bdcc97) which shows an unimplemented PIC write). So it's not a software interrupt in the `INT` sense but is actually, put simply, a hardware interrupt. It then lowers the IRQL back from 31 to the previous IRQL (which was the ISR IRQL). It then returns to the ISR and then it will return to `KiInterruptDispatch`; `KiInterruptDispatch` will then release the ISR spinlock using `KeReleaseInterruptSpinLock` which will reduce the IRQL to what it was before the interrupt and it then pop the trap frame but I would have thought it would first pop the trap frame and then program the LAPIC TPR so the register restore process is atomic but I suppose it doesn't really matter.

ReactOS has the following (WRK doesn't have `KeReleaseSpinlock` or the IRQL lowering procedures documented so this is the best we have):

```
VOID NTAPI KeReleaseSpinLock ( KIRQL NewIrql )
    {
    /* Release the lock and lower IRQL back */
    KxReleaseSpinLock(SpinLock);
    KeLowerIrql(OldIrql);
    }

VOID FASTCALL KfReleaseSpinLock ( PKSPIN_LOCK SpinLock, KIRQL OldIrql )
    {
    /* Simply lower IRQL back */
    KeLowerIrql(OldIrql);
    }
```

KeLowerIrql is a wrapper for the HAL function KfLowerIrql, the function contains `KfLowerIrql(OldIrql);` and that's it.

```
VOID FASTCALL KfLowerIrql ( KIRQL NewIrql )
    {
     DPRINT("KfLowerIrql(NewIrql %d)\n", NewIrql);

     if (NewIrql > KeGetPcr()->Irql)
     {
         DbgPrint ("(%s:%d) NewIrql %x CurrentIrql %x\n",
         __FILE__, __LINE__, NewIrql, KeGetPcr()->Irql);
         KeBugCheck(IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL);
         for(;;);
     }
     HalpLowerIrql(NewIrql);
 }
```

This function basically prevents the new IRQL being higher than the current IRQL which makes sense because the function is supposed to lower the IRQL. If everything is ok, the function calls `HalpLowerIrql(NewIrql);` This is a skeleton of a multiprocessor AMD64 implementation -- it does not actually implement the APIC register writes (or MSRs for x2APIC), they are empty functions on ReactOS's multiprocessor AMD64 implementation as it is in development; but on windows, they wont be and they'll actually program the LAPIC TPR so that the queued software interrupt can now occur.

```
HalpLowerIrql(KIRQL NewIrql, BOOLEAN FromHalEndSystemInterrupt)
 {
   ULONG Flags;
   UCHAR DpcRequested;
   if (NewIrql >= DISPATCH_LEVEL)
     {
       KeSetCurrentIrql (NewIrql);
       APICWrite(APIC_TPR, IRQL2TPR (NewIrql) & APIC_TPR_PRI);
       return;
     }
   Flags = __readeflags();
   if (KeGetCurrentIrql() > APC_LEVEL)
     {
       KeSetCurrentIrql (DISPATCH_LEVEL);
       APICWrite(APIC_TPR, IRQL2TPR (DISPATCH_LEVEL) & APIC_TPR_PRI);
       DpcRequested = __readfsbyte(FIELD_OFFSET(KIPCR, HalReserved[HAL_DPC_REQUEST]));
       if (FromHalEndSystemInterrupt || DpcRequested)
         {
           __writefsbyte(FIELD_OFFSET(KIPCR, HalReserved[HAL_DPC_REQUEST]), 0);
           _enable();
           KiDispatchInterrupt();
           if (!(Flags & EFLAGS_INTERRUPT_MASK))
             {
               _disable();
             }
     }
       KeSetCurrentIrql (APC_LEVEL);
     }
   if (NewIrql == APC_LEVEL)
     {
       return;
     }
   if (KeGetCurrentThread () != NULL &&
       KeGetCurrentThread ()->ApcState.KernelApcPending)
     {
       _enable();
       KiDeliverApc(KernelMode, NULL, NULL);
       if (!(Flags & EFLAGS_INTERRUPT_MASK))
         {
           _disable();
         }
     }
   KeSetCurrentIrql (PASSIVE_LEVEL);
 }
```

Firstly, it checks to see if the new IRQL is above dispatch level, if so, it sets it to it just fine and writes to the LAPIC TPR register and returns. If not, it checks to see if the current IRQL is dispatch level (`>APC_LEVEL`). It means that by definition, the new IRQL is going to be *less* than dispatch level. We can see that in this event it makes it equal to `DISPATCH_LEVEL` rather than letting it drop below and writes it to the LAPIC TPR register. It then checks is `HalReserved[HAL_DPC_REQUEST]` which appears to be what ReactOS uses instead of `DpcInterruptRequested` which we saw previously, so just substitute it with that. It then sets it to 0 (note the PCR begins at the start of segment descriptor pointed to by the FS segment in kernel mode). It then enables interrupts and calls `KiDispatchInterrupt` and after that if the `eflags` register changed the IF flag during `KiDispatchInterrupt` it disables interrupts. It then also checks to see if a kernel APC is pending (which is beyond the scope of this explanation) before finally setting the IRQL to passive level

```
VOID NTAPI KiDispatchInterrupt ( VOID )
 {
     PKIPCR Pcr = (PKIPCR)KeGetPcr();
     PKPRCB Prcb = &Pcr->Prcb;
     PKTHREAD NewThread, OldThread;

     /* Disable interrupts */
     _disable();

     /* Check for pending timers, pending DPCs, or pending ready threads */
     if ((Prcb->DpcData[0].DpcQueueDepth) ||
         (Prcb->TimerRequest) ||
         (Prcb->DeferredReadyListHead.Next))
     {
         /* Retire DPCs while under the DPC stack */
         //KiRetireDpcListInDpcStack(Prcb, Prcb->DpcStack);
         // FIXME!!! //
         KiRetireDpcList(Prcb);
     }

     /* Re-enable interrupts */
     _enable();

     /* Check for quantum end */
     if (Prcb->QuantumEnd)
     {
         /* Handle quantum end */
         Prcb->QuantumEnd = FALSE;
         KiQuantumEnd();
     }
     else if (Prcb->NextThread)
     {
         /* Capture current thread data */
         OldThread = Prcb->CurrentThread;
         NewThread = Prcb->NextThread;

         /* Set new thread data */
         Prcb->NextThread = NULL;
         Prcb->CurrentThread = NewThread;

         /* The thread is now running */
         NewThread->State = Running;
         OldThread->WaitReason = WrDispatchInt;

         /* Make the old thread ready */
         KxQueueReadyThread(OldThread, Prcb);

         /* Swap to the new thread */
         KiSwapContext(APC_LEVEL, OldThread);
     }
 }
```

Firstly, it disables interrupts _disable is just a wrapper of an asm block that clears the IF flag and has memory and cc in the clobber list (to prevent compiler reordering). This looks like arm syntax though.

```
 {
     __asm__ __volatile__
     (
      "cpsid i    @ __cli" : : : "memory", "cc"
     );
 }
```

This ensures that it can drain the DPC queue as an uninterrupted procedure; as with interrupts disabled, it cannot be interrupted by a clock interrupt and rescheduled. This prevents the scenario of 2 schedulers running at the same time for instance if a thread yielded with `Sleep()` it ends up calling `KeRaiseIrqlToSynchLevel` which is analogous to disabling interrupts. This will prevent a timer interrupt interrupting it and scheduling another thread switch over the top of the currently executing thread switch procedure -- it ensures that scheduling is atomic.

It checks to see if there are DPCs on the normal queue of the current core or whether there is a timer expiry or deferred ready threads and then calls [`KiRetireDpcList`](https://doxygen.reactos.org/d9/d85/ntoskrnl_2include_2internal_2ke_8h.html#afe4303889868fcf9b40b0361859d87df) which basically contains a while queue depth != 0 loop which first checks to see if it is a timer expiry request (which I won't go into now), if not, acquires the DPC queue spinlock, takes a DPC off the queue and parses the members into arguments (interrupts still disabled), decreases queue depth, drops spinlock, enables interrupts and calls the `DeferredRoutine`. When the `DeferredRoutine` returns, it disables interrupts again and if there are more in the queue it reacquires the spinlock (spinlock and interrupts disabled ensure that the DPC removal from the queue is atomic so that another interrupt and hence DPC queue drain does not work on the same DPC — it will be already removed from the queue). Since the DPC queue spinlock is not implemented yet on ReactOS we can postulate what might happen on windows: if it fails to acquire the spinlock then given that it's a spinlock and that we are still at `DISPATCH_LEVEL` and interrupts are disabled, it would spin until the thread on the other core calls `KeReleaseSpinLockFromDpcLevel(&DpcData->DpcLock);` which is not that much holdup as each thread has the spinlock for about 100 uops I'd say, so we can afford to have interrupts disabled at `DISPATCH_LEVEL`.

Note that the drain procedure only ever drains the queue of the current core. When the DPC queue is empty, it reenables interrupts and checks to see if there are any deferred ready threads and makes them all ready. It then returns down the callchain to `KiInterruptTemplate` and then the ISR officially ends.

So, as an overview, in `KeInsertQueuedpc`, if the DPC to queue is to another core and it is of high priority or the queue depth exceeds the maximum defined in the PRCB then it sets the DpcRequested flag in the PRCB of the core and sends an IPI to the core which most likely runs `KiDispatchInterrupt` in some way (the ISR could just be the IRQL lower procedure that indeed calls `KiDispatchinterrupt`) which will drain the DPC queue on that core; the actual wrapper that calls `KiDispatchinterrupt` may or may not disable the DpcRequested flag in the PRCB like `HalpLowerIrql` does but I don't know, it may indeed be `HalpLowerIrql` as I suggested. After `KeInsertQueuedpc`, when it lowers the IRQL, nothing happens because the DpcRequested flag is in the other core and not the current core. If the DPC to queue is targeted at the current core then if it is of high or medium priority or the queue depth has exceeded the maximum queue depth and the DPC rate is less than the minimum rate defined in the PRCB then it sets the DpcRequested flag in the PRCB and requests a self IPI which will call the same generic wrapper which is used by the scheduler as well so probably something like `HalpLowerIrql`. After `KeInsertQueuedpc` it lowers the IRQL with `HalpLowerIrql` and sees `DpcRequested` so drains the queue of the current core before lowering IRQL.

Do you see the problem with this though? WRK shows a 'software' interrupt being requested (whose ISR probably calls `KiDispatchInterrupt` as it is a multi-purpose function and there is only one function that is ever used: 
`KiRequestSoftwareInterrupt(DISPATCH_LEVEL) in all scenarios`) but then ReactOS shows `KiDispatchInterrupt` being called when the IRQL drops *as well*. You'd expect that when `KiInterruptDispatch` drops the ISR spinlock, the function to do so would just check for deferred ready threads or timer expiry request and then just drop the IRQL because the software interrupt to drain the queue will happen as soon as the LAPIC TPR is programmed but ReactOS actually checks for items on the queue (using the flag on the PRCB) and initiates the queue draining in the procedure to lower the IRQL. There is no WRK source code for the spinlock releasing but let's assume that it just doesn't do what happens on ReactOS and lets the 'software' interrupt handle it -- perhaps it leaves that whole DPC queue check out of its equivalent of `HalpLowerIrql`. But wait a second, what's the `Prcb->DpcInterruptRequested` for then if it's not used for initiating the queue draining like on ReactOS? Perhaps it is merely used as a control variable so that it doesn't queue 2 software interrupts. We also note that ReactOS also [requests a 'software' interrupt at this stage](https://doxygen.reactos.org/d1/d92/dpc_8c.html#a0af285a1d39243f12185b860548b260c) (to arm's Vectored Interrupt Controller) which is extremely odd. So maybe not then. This blatantly does suggests that it gets called twice. It appears that it drains the queue and then the 'software' interrupt comes in immediately after when the IRQL drops (which most likely also calls `KiRetireDpcList` at some stage) both on ReactOS and WRK and does the same thing. I wonder what anyone makes of that. I mean why both Self IPI and then drain the queue anyway? One of these actions is redundant.

As for lazy IRQL. I see no evidence of it on the WRK or ReactOS, but where it would be implemented would be `KiInterruptDispatch`. It would be possible to get the current IRQL using `KeGetCurrentIrql` and then comparing it to the IRQL of the interrupt object *and then* programming the TPR to correspond to the current IRQL. It either quiesces the interrupt and queues another for that vector using a self IPI or it would just simply switch trap frames.