# How to identify a HID after it's moved to a different port on Windows

Tags: windows, usb, uniqueidentifier, hid, serial-number

I'm on Windows and am trying to store calibration data for game controllers connected via USB and am trying to find a value which uniquely identifies them in a port independent way.

There is the [`HidD_GetSerialNumberString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/hidsdi/nf-hidsdi-hidd_getserialnumberstring) function but i've [read here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72512840/1280961) that it's uncommon for devices to have serial numbers and indeed when i try to read one f.e. from a PS4 controller `HidD_GetSerialNumberString` returns `FALSE` and [`GetLastError`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/errhandlingapi/nf-errhandlingapi-getlasterror) returns [`ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/system-error-codes--0-499-).

Is there any other data available which can be accessed to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [instance ID](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows-hardware/drivers/install/instance-ids) for your HID device (call [CM_Get_Device_Interface_Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/win32/api/cfgmgr32/nf-cfgmgr32-cm_get_device_interface_propertyw) with `device interface path` and [DEVPKEY_Device_InstanceId](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows-hardware/drivers/install/devpkey-device-instanceid) property and use string after last `&` char). It should be unique and persistent per system restarts. But it is not guaranteed if serial number is not provided (in this case `instance ID` will be different if device is plugged into different usb port)...

More info on this here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56885175/1795050